# algorithm for using download speed to increase upload speed

Tags: algorithm, upload, download

I was wondering if there's any whitepaper or research on the topic of using a dataflow in one direction to increase the dataflow in the other direction. Assuming we have the cpu power of a normal desktop computer, and compressed data. I can see two possible use cases:

1. Asymmetric upload/download speeds (at least 10x difference, maybe over 100x)
2. Only being charged for data transferred one way

with two possible goal strategies:

1. Send some data as fast as possible using both normal upload and this technique
2. Send some data soon-ish, more targeted at the 2nd use case.

In this example we have a lot of bandwidth from the server to the client, but not the other way around.

We're going to focus on the 1st goal strategy too, since the second one is really just a 0-bit response and an "infinite" amount of time to transfer any kind of data. Just send all permutations one by one and when the client gets the correct one it responds with a 0-bit message.

I can think of a few naive ways of implementing this, such as simply guessing what data should be sent from client to server next, sending an id number with each data stream, modulo some number, such as 2^16, to allow some overlap. If there's a match, the client tells the server just the id number of the correct block. The server uses the last block it sent with that id number. If the guesses are good enough, we should be able to get some data transferred.

I'm guessing this might not be the best stackexchange site for this question, but I couldn't figure out which one fits best. I'm guessing StackOverflow, Mathematics, MathOverflow, Computer science or Theoretical Computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting idea but I see some problems/limitations:

If the factor is about 100 you can download 100 bits while sending one, so if we ignore limitations of transmission overhead, latency etc, we could download about all 4-bit combinations (16*4bit=64) while upload one bit (for 5 bit we need a factor of 32*5=160). So an upper bound for speedup would be 4 times the original upload sped.

**Problem:** I believe your question is related on a data transfer via IP.

- The *overhead* sending this small 4-bit packages would be much much higher than what you gain.
- to be sure which 4.bit block was meant by the upload bit, you need to wait between the sending of the 4-bit packages for a possible upload bit, which means you have to wait at least two times the *latency* of your connection which is that high that you will gain nothing at the end.

Comment: Yes, of course there's some overhead, but I think we can think about it as a 1bit overhead (start-bit or similar) just for the sake of if :)

Answer (score 1):

unless you have a prediction algorithm, I don't think you are gonna get much benefit. to explain I will try to describe your situation in simple examples.

imagine your client can send information 1bit/second and your server having more bandwidth can send 8bits/second

if your client needs to send a single byte and receive an acknowledge it will take at least 8 seconds

- client -> 1..0..1..1..0..1..0..1 //8 seconds to send a byte
- server -> 1 // plus 1/8th of a second to get response

what you are suggesting is that server sends the data (querying if it is correct) and the client simply responds yes or no

- server -> 1..0..1..1..0..1..0..1 //1 seconds to send a byte
- client -> 1 // plus 1 of a second acknowledge

so the server knows the client, wished to send 10110101 and this indeed only takes 2 seconds compared to the previous 8.

but the problem is that the search space is huge (8bit combinations) so unless the server has a very good prediction system that allows it to find the correct byte with up to 4 tries it will take much more time for the server to guess, what the client wanted, than for the client to send it in the first place. example

- server -> (did you wish to send)00000001? client -> 0 //no
- server -> (did you wish to send)00000010? client -> 0 //no
- server -> (did you wish to send)00000011? client -> 0 //no
- server -> (did you wish to send)00000100? client -> 0 //no
- 8 second mark!
- server -> (did you wish to send)00000101? client -> 0 //no
- ....
- server -> (did you wish to send)10110101? client -> 1 //yes/worst case scenarios is 256 communications

as you see, it doesn't pay to try to guess.. and even if you try to expand this into into alternate forms, and send chunks or buffers with more data, the problem remains. if information space is x bits , the mininum the client will have to send is x bits to acknowledge the data.

the only way to avoid this is if the server guesses are spot on.. but if the server is that good in guessing what the client wanted.. the he probably didn't needs to ask in the first place, and that information is probably redundant.

so even if some optimization is possible using this technique. I don't think is a reliable method of speeding up communications.

### another example

another example non computer/bandwidth related that I think may sum up the problem better

Imagine I have a bunch of numbers `231,594,673,123,167,565,907,450,758,165`, you peek one and you try to tell me which with the minimal amount of information.

So you say `it starts with digit 1`, but I still have `123,167,165` possibilities, so you will have to say `next digit is 6`  and I get `167,165`, I'm still not sure which one, so you are forced to say `ends in 5`.

By this time your have given me the 3 digits, I can pin point the number, but its was necessary for you to give-me **all** the digits. you might just told me `165` in the first place. Basically if you have several items each one distinguished by some combination of properties, the only way to identify a single one is by describing all of the properties. and the most simple and direct is always just to give that information. Any other process will only make it worse.

Comment: The client could just stay silent until the correct one is found

Comment: eve if it was silent you would still, consume time from the server, so instead of 2 seconds, per message you would take 1 seconds, but the worst case instead of 256 * 2sec would still be 256*1sec.. much worst that the time the client take to sen the data